# JS, updating duplicate properties of objects in large array

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, object, duplicates

i've got an array of objects that look something like this:

```
var object =[ 
  {
    'Pizza': 0,
    'SOMEVALUE': 1
  },
  {
    'Pizza': 0,
    'SOMEVALUE': 15
  },
  {
    'Car': 1,
    'SOMEVALUE': 1
  }   
    ];
```

is there an faster way to update all 'Pizza' & 'Car' fields with the same value?
(eg. all pizzas where pizza == 0)

currently i'm just looping through them which becomes very slow when there are multiple values in each array.

https://jsfiddle.net/txybLq1v/1/

Comment: *object might contain up to a million items* - suggest you find a better way to handle this much data, such as a server-side database with ajax queries / POST updates.   Databases are designed for this sort of thing, javascript is not.

Comment: well yes, but even doing this serverside it would still do the same loops, updating each property **individually**.

i'm looking for a method to update all duplicate fields **at once** if possible

Comment: No, server side would be something like `update table set somevalue = somevalue + 1 where pizza = 0` as databases use *set based operations* and would be near instantaneous (depending on hardware) for a million items.  It may not fit your exact scenario as I can't really see what you're trying to do in your fiddle - but the concept is that it's set-based so does all the fields "at once".

Comment: Please note that the comments/advice above doesn't preclude someone providing a javascript answer; they're only suggestions.

Comment: well the basic idea is the same as translating strings from one language to other.
(id -> name with this id)


I have all the translations(groupdata) loaded,
and all the data(object) loaded which hasn't been translated yet.


all this data then gets sent to a grid, and shown to the user.


all is fine but all the pizzanames/carnames are just numbers, that get updated after a minute or so when this gets finished running.